# add x lagged value to a tbl

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a tibble like this:

```
df <- tibble(value = rnorm(500))
```

how can I add x (e.g. x = 10) lagged values to this tbl (ideally in a dplyr pipe)? I want to add these lagged variables as new columns.

I can do it for a single lag:

```
lag_df <- df %>%
  mutate(value_lag = lag(value, n = 1)) %>%   # first lag
  filter(!is.na(value_lag))    # remove NA
```

doing it manually for 3 lags would look like this:

```
lag_df <- df %>%
  mutate(value_lag1 = lag(value, n = 1)) %>%   # first lag
  mutate(value_lag2 = lag(value, n = 2)) %>%   # second lag
  mutate(value_lag3 = lag(value, n = 3)) %>%   # third lag
  filter(!is.na(value_lag1))    # remove NA
  filter(!is.na(value_lag2))    # remove NA
  filter(!is.na(value_lag3))    # remove NA
```

Comment: @RonakShah yes I want to add each lag as a new column. Think of `value` as a time series where first rows are observed first. Of course the first row does not have any lag value and is therefore NA, but the dplyr lag functions handles that automatically

Answer (score 1):

Not a complete `dplyr` solution but one way is to create a column for each lagged value and `cbind` it to the original daatframe and remove the rows with `NA` values with `na.omit()`

```
library(dplyr)
cbind(df, sapply(1:10, function(x) lag(df$value, n = x))) %>%
   na.omit()
```

---

An ugly attempt to keep it completely in `tidyverse` with my broken skills

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(n=1:10)  %>% mutate(output = map2(list(df),n ,function(x,y){
    x %>% mutate(value = lag(value,y))
})) %>% spread(n,output) %>% unnest() %>% na.omit()
```

The base R method is much cleaner than this but there should definitely be a better way to do it than this.

---

And a bit shorter version

```
map2(list(df), 1:10, function(x, y) {
  x %>% mutate(value = lag(value,y))
    }) %>%
bind_cols() %>% na.omit()
```